# How to get the value which is selected in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I click on a row I should get the value on which the user is clicked

How do I get that?

Comment: Can you be more specific about which grid control you are using?

Comment: what do you mean by "value of the row"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about one of these event:

- [`DataGridView.CellClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellclick.aspx)
- [`DataGridView.CellContentClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellcontentclick.aspx)
- [`DataGridView.RowEnter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowenter.aspx)

Comment: Define what is row enter plzz

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly, then you'll want the [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event.

Answer (score 0):

If the grid's SelectionMode is set to FullRowSelect or FullHeaderSelect, you can get the selected row(s), using

[DataGridView.SelectedRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows.aspx)

Then for each row you can use the Cells property to get the values.

There are a wide variety of ways to get at the underlying data set.